# TweenJS with Images

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, tween, createjs

i have got a problem to animate a image from x=0 to x=400. i´m using easeljs and tweenjs.
here is my code:
Javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/easeljs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tweenjs-0.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var stage = new Stage(canvas);
            var img=new Image();

            img.src="http://exampledomain.com/exampleimage.jpg";
            img.onload = function(e){
                var title = new Bitmap(e.target);
                stage.addChild(title);
                stage.update();
            }
            var tween = Tween.get(img).to({x:400},400).call(tweenComplete);
        }

        function tweenComplete(){
            alert('done');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="430" height="446"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

im sure that the tween starts, because after 400ms opens the alert but the image doesn´t move one pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a couple of minor things are conspiring to break the code.

First, a bit of a race condition.  You properly create the Bitmap and add it to the Stage in the `img.onload()`, but the `var tween = ...` code right after it can run anytime, including **before** the Bitmap has been created/added.

Try moving the `var tween = ...` line to the end of your `img.onload` function and change the `get(img)` to `get(title)` so you can act on the Bitmap instead of the Image.

Finally, you need to get the Ticker moving so the Stage will update.  Try something like this at the end of `init()`:

```
Ticker.addListener(stage);
```

[Note for anyone using later versions of CreateJS, you'll need to namespace/prepend "createjs." to the uses of Stage, Bitmap, Ticker, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

You must animate your Bitmap, not the image inside of it. Store a reference to the Bitmap instance you create, and set the x/y of that instead.

Answer (score 0):

set the initial x,y coordinated of tile(image) from where you are going to animate it. 
use image object title as get(title) in spite of get(img) in tweening and also use a ticker for countinuous updation
cretajs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick',function(){stage.update();})